# Pathfinding with direction considerations

Tags: unity, c#, ai, path-finding

Consider the following road network. The car (orange) needs to get to the red circle. It drives on the right hand side of the road and is initially facing down.

The shortest path is the blue one. But if it follows this path, it reaches the red circle on the wrong side of the road. To actually get to the red circle, it needs to take the green path - much longer. The pink dots represent the nodes - the road network is made up of modular road pieces. Each node also stores all the possible directions a vehicle could take from that piece.

How can I make a pathfinding algorithm that takes this into consideration?

[image]

Comment: Do you know on which side of the road the goal is ?

Comment: Yes. I know the position and orientation (and thus the side of road) the goal is. The goal isn't necessarily at a pink node - it could be between them but it will always be on a straight section.

Comment: If being on the left side of the road is different than being on the right side of the road, then those two states need to be two different nodes. Once you've created nodes for the distinct states you care about, and set up their adjacency graph correctly, a completely vanilla pathfinding algorithm will find the shortest path that puts you on the correct side of the road.

Comment: What about reverse pathfinding ? From the goal to the car, this way you can vanish out cells that are in opposite side of the road ?

Comment: Then I have the same problem but at the other end. If I go from the red dot along the blue line, I will end up on the wrong side. I would have to go right at the T intersection and loop back around.

Comment: No, if your goal is on the right side, then only car that goes to the left direction can pass, so you completely block the road segment from the goal to the closer pink node to the left... well yes direction of pathfinding doesnt actually matters here.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "pass"? How would you know that the road segment in the lower left corner will be on the wrong side of the road to the car at the end? They're both on the right hand side (locally), but at the end they are opposite directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each purple dot in your image will be represented by multiple nodes in the graph.  Each graph-node will not only represent the car's position, but also the direction it came from.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is the "graph"? And how would I represent a corner in the graph.

Comment: @mr-matt: A [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) is the fundamental object needed to run [A\*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).  It's too large of a subject to get into in the comments, but there is a plethora of material online. You literally cannot use A\* without understanding what a graph is.

Comment: Ok I see. Can you explain the part about storing the direction each graph-node came from? I'm not sure I understand how that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use filtering. 
For example you can assign a filter to the car lest say a bitmask, then you can assign filter to cells (assuming it is a grid system).

When you run your ASTAR (assuming it is an astar) you can calculate cell cost or passibility by the filter masks - for example if the car has right filter mask then all the left filter masked cells will become impassible.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work. I've updated the screenshot with the node positions. I have one node for each road piece - the network is made up of modular roads. I'm not sure how I would divide that up to have a node on each side of the road. It won't work so well around the corners.

Comment: @mr-matt Sorry, guess I misread the question